# Multithreading issue with HttpClient

Tags: java, multithreading, http

I'm running into a multithreading issue with HttpClient where I have the following scenario:

Thread A will issue url http://blap.com?param=2

Thread B will issue url http://blap.com?param=3

and this works about 98% of the time, but occasionally Thread A will receive the data for Thread B's url and vice-versa.

Now each thread is creating it's own HttpClient instance so I thought in theory I wouldn't need to use MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.

Does the behavior I'm describing seem plausible and will it be fixed by using MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager?

I'm using java 1.6 and apache http client components 4.0.3.

Update:
Here's the function in question.

```
public void get_url(String strDataSet) throws SQLException, MalformedURLException, IOException
{

      String query;



        query = "select * from jobs where data_set='" + strDataSet + "'";

        ResultSet rs2 = dbf.db_run_query(query);
        rs2.next();


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;



            String strURL;
            strURL = rs2.getString("url_static");

            if (rs2.getString("url_dynamic")!=null && !rs2.getString("url_dynamic").isEmpty())
                strURL = strURL.replace("${dynamic}", rs2.getString("url_dynamic"));

            UtilityFunctions.stdoutwriter.writeln("Retrieving URL: " + strURL,Logs.STATUS2,"DG25");

            if (!strURL.contains(":"))
                UtilityFunctions.stdoutwriter.writeln("WARNING: url is not preceeded with a protocol" + strURL,Logs.STATUS1,"DG25.5");

            //HttpGet chokes on the ^ character

            strURL = strURL.replace("^","%5E");


            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(strURL); 


            /*
             * The following line fixes an issue where a non-fatal error is displayed about an invalid cookie data format.
             * It turns out that some sites generate a warning with this code, and others without it.
             * I'm going to kludge this for now until I get more data on which urls throw the
             * warning and which don't.
             * 
             * warning with code: www.exchange-rates.org
             */


                if (!(strCurDataSet.contains("xrateorg") || strCurDataSet.contains("google") || strCurDataSet.contains("mwatch")))
                {
                    httpget.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.cookie-datepatterns", 
                            Arrays.asList("EEE, dd MMM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss z", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"));
                }







            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);




         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    entity.getContent()));



      int nTmp;         

      returned_content="";




      while ((nTmp = in.read()) != -1)
        returned_content = returned_content + (char)nTmp;


      in.close();

      httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

      UtilityFunctions.stdoutwriter.writeln("Done reading url contents",Logs.STATUS2,"DG26");



}
```

Update: 
I narrowed the problem down to the line:

```
response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

If I put a thread lock around that line, the problem went away. The thing is, that's the most time consuming piece and I don't want only one thread to be able to retrieve http data at a time.

Comment: This method looks like it does lot of non-connected things all at once: fetching URL from DB, validating that URL, reading from corresponding HTTP connection. Have you considered to refactor it into several classes for easier maintenance and unit-testing? By the way, what if `rs.next()` returns `false`? In current code race condition may be anywhere, even at DB level.

Answer (score 0):

Your code's not thread-safe.  To fix your immediate problem, you need to declare your `HttpClient` as a `ThreadLocal`, but there's a lot more to fix.

Comment: I'm not seeing the benefit of making HttpClient threadlocal. Threadlocal makes it global within the thread but this is the only method that uses the variable. Any specifics on what else isn't thread safe would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new HttpContext in each thread and pass it to HttpClient.execute:

```
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpClient();
response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
```

See the bottom of this doc (from HttpClient 4):

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html

Also there's a thread safe HttpContext implementation (SyncBasicHttpContext) but I'm not sure if you would need it in this case.